# Google Chrome's window becomes invisible / unresponsive

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde, window, kde4

I'm using Google Chrome, Version 39 (64-bit), under Kubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (trusty).

Often, the browser's window becomes invisible after returning from standby, or after opening the window after it was minimized (either by clicking on it in the panel or selecting it among open windows with Alt+Tab).

The only thing that helps to make Chrome visible again is to switch to a TTY by Ctrl+Alt+F1-6 and then back to GUI with Ctrl+Alt+F7.

This has been quite annoying. I would greatly appreciate any solutions/workarounds?

UPDATE: I notice that it happens almost every time after standby/lockscreen when Chrome's window has been in the foreground before.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be connected to the compositer feature of KDE4 (or with Desktop Effects). If the Chrome window becomes invisible click Alt + Shift + F12 to switch on compositing and it will become visible instantaneously. I could no longer reproduce this behaviour with compositing on.

Comment: May I ask why you were using KDE4 without composition ?

Answer (score -2):

I want to tell you to use Firefox as a solution (bad joke) :)

Otherwise

Try this

Open terminal,

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge google-chrome-stable
```

after that, re-install one of this version

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable
```

if you want to install via https://www.google.co.in/chrome/browser/ or wget

32bit

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

64bit

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get -f install
```

You have many options now probably one of that can solve your problem

Comment: So you are telling me to reinstall the browser? :) And test the latest, less stable versions?

Comment: Tried all that. No success.