# Google-chrome window loading problem - invisible

Tags: google-chrome

I'am having problems with new verision of google-chrome. After updating it after 2 months one really annoying problem initiated. I'am using awesome window manager and when I switch desktop to that where chrome is located I can't see window until I get my mouse over it. This image describes it fully:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/TGSsc8x.gif]

I found a similar topic, but with no result:

[Google Chrome's window becomes invisible / unresponsive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/575341/google-chromes-window-becomes-invisible-unresponsive)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem before.  To fix it I disabled the compositer and the problem went away.   It is kind of a lame fix but it has worked for me multiple times in the past.